# Querying PurchaseOrderNumber returns all PurchaseOrders

Tags: php, xero-api

I'm trying to query for a specific purchase order using the "PurchaseOrderNumber" field, however regardless of what value I provide, all PurchaseOrders are returned.

I've replicated the exact same code except swapped out for Invoices and the querying of "InvoiceNumber" works fine, just not PurchaseOrders.

Here's the URL I'm calling:

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/PurchaseOrders?where=PurchaseOrderNumber%3D%3D%22PO-0007%22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query purchase orders both by Id and Purchase order number.
So your request would look something like

api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/PurchaseOrders/PO-0001

PO-0001 can be substituted by the actual id as well.

Look at xero documentation [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/purchase-orders#get), and the optional parameters section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers! Xero responded directly saying that the PurchaseOrder model doesn't support "where" searches like the Invoice model does, so your answer solves the problem.